# How to return function columns with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have a function with about 40 columns with null values and these columns have never been used for the past 5 years. So I want to write a query that confirms that these fields have null values. I have used a select query below:

```
select col1, col2, col3, .....coln
from dbo.fn_functionName(DATEADD(YEAR, -5, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),'','','','')
```

The problem with this query is that, Its returning over 10 000 records and my clients are not satisfied.

Comment: Would you like to display only the records that have null values in the 40 columns to the Client or your expectation is to omit the rows that have null and output the rest.

Comment: What are they not satisfied with: the fact that there are so many rows, or the fact that your solution returns too much data? Or is it that your solution returns columns that it shouldn't? It's very hard to tell from your question, you probably should elaborate on it.

Comment: Hi Prokhorov,They are not satisfied with the fact that the query returns too much data. My expectations is to display columns that have null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query to check if any column contains a null:

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @tb = N'dbo.[table]';

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb + ' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Might help. Also you can just check if important columns are null's and display only valid ones:

```
select *
from tabName
where col1 is not null and col6 is not null...
```

At the end You can think about creating second table 1 to 1 with old values, if they are important. All the tables need to be refreshed time to time :)
EDIT:
I think that is similar to the query you are looking for:

```
  Select [TransactionID] , [ProductID] ,[ReferenceOrderID] ,[ReferenceOrderLineID], [TransactionDate] ,[TransactionType] ,[Quantity],[ActualCost] ,[ModifiedDate]
    from tableName
    where datediff(year,[TransactionDate], GETDATE()) < 5
          and ([ProductID] is not null and [ProductID] != '')
          and ([TransactionType] is not null and [TransactionType] != '')
          and ([Quantity] is not null)
          and [ActualCost] is not null
```

Ok, so what is going on in this query? After select you are listing columns you want to be displayed. If you need all of them just type "select *". Then you choose the table (by selecting it) and here comes the magic.
datediff(year, date1,date2) counts difference between two dates. To check todays date just type GETDATE(). Than other conditions. Unlike normal programming languages you can't type "something != null", you need to use "something is not null". Sometimes you'll have to check if it's null or empty string. So

```
 ([ProductID] is not null and [ProductID] != '')
```

I hope that helped :)

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz, I have tried this method but its not working for me. I have replaced the table name with a function name and its not working. I am pretty new to SQL, can you help me please?

Comment: yapp :) What is your goal? Could you please list a columns you want to display (if not all) and list a columns you want to have some value? And table name. I'll write it for you :)

Comment: SQL becomes easy if you practice a lot, so do not care about negative comments. All you need is to practice, so am I and all the people in the world  :)

Comment: Here is the list of columns: [TransactionID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[ReferenceOrderID]
      ,[ReferenceOrderLineID]
      ,[TransactionDate]
      ,[TransactionType]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[ActualCost]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[ReferenceOrderID]
      ,[ReferenceOrderLineID]
      ,[TransactionDate]
      ,[TransactionType]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[ActualCost]
      ,[ModifiedDate]








Here is how the function must be called:
dbo.fn_functionName(DATEADD(YEAR, -5, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),'','','','')

Comment: ok, now which columns has to be not null? And can't you just check if [ModifiedDate] or [TransactionDate] is older than 5 years instead of using this function?

Comment: Are all your columns inside one talbe or this function of yours contains some joins?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I needed to use:

```
  Select [TransactionID] , [ProductID] ,[ReferenceOrderID] ,[ReferenceOrderLineID], [TransactionDate] ,[TransactionType] ,[Quantity],[ActualCost] ,[ModifiedDate]
    from tableName
    where datediff(year,[TransactionDate], GETDATE()) < 5
          and ([ProductID] is not null and [ProductID] != '')
          and ([TransactionType] is not null and [TransactionType] != '')
          and ([Quantity] is not null)
          and [ActualCost] is not null
```